# Can't remove records from DataGrid when it binded to Dictionary<,>

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have some Dictionary with data. I use it as an ItemsSource for my WPF DataGrid.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic.Add("1st", "entry");
            dic.Add("2nd", "entry 2");
            dic.Add("3rd", "entry 3");

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dic;

<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Why is it not letting me delete rows? :(

Comment: temporary use bad solution with handling row deleting event and manually removing entries from my observable dictionary :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not work because Dictionary do not implement IEditableCollectionView. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx) is a nice overview for the editing features of the datagrid.

but you can do the deleting by your self. Create a command with parameter selected items from your datagrid and delete the items from your dictionary by your self. at this time you should think about using a ObservableCollection as an intemssource because of notifying the view.

Comment: Okay, I create class which implements IDictionary and IEditableCollectionView interfaces, but it doesn't work too :(.

Comment: I have custom observable dictionary class, so notifying is not problem. And I want use Dictionary instead of simple collection, because I want bind it to datagrid and use "access by key" feature in code (for example: datagrid.DataSource = myDic; myDic["somekey"].Phrase = "new phrase text";